# saving a model with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called theaters which stores info on theaters.

I list the theaters based on a zipcode searched for by the user.  The user can then click on an individual theater and show reviews for it.  If they are logged in they can add a review.

So my models are:

> Theaters has_many reviews
>
> User has many reviews
>
> Reviews belongs to user and has one theater

When submitting the new review I am doing this (@theater_id is passed as a param via the add review submit button):

```
def create
      @user_id = current_user
      @review = Review.create(review_params.merge(:user_id => @user_id,:theater_id => @theater_id))
      if @review.save
        redirect_to @review
      else 
        render 'edit'
      end
   end
```

I feel like because of my associations there is an easier more rails-correct way to do this.  Like rails should automagically put in my current user id and theater id...  right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Nested Resources**

I don't know how your `routes` are set up, but this is typically within the realm of [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), where your `reviews` objects will be created under `theatre` objects:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :theatres do
   resources :reviews #-> domain.com/theatres/1/reviews/new
end
```

When you use routing like this, it sets an extra param in your `controller`, called `theatre_id`, which you can use to populate your new `Review` object:

```
#app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
Class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @review = Review.new(review_params)
       @review.save 
   end

   private

   def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:your, :params).merge(theatre_id: params[:theatre_id]
   end
end
```

--

Alternatively, you could set the `theatre` object of your new `ActiveRecord` object:

```
#app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
Class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
   def create
       @theatre = Theatre.find params[:theatre_id]

       @review = Review.new(review_params)
       @review.theatre = @theatre
       @review.save
   end
end
```